# How do I address Daru Vectors in a DataFrame using symbols rather than strings?

Tags: ruby, dataframe, symbols, daru

I see this happening in a lot of online code examples, but when I parse my CSV file, all I get are strings as column indices, like

```
> data = Daru::DataFrame.from_csv('my_fancy_data.csv')
> data[:user_id]
IndexError: Specified index :user_id does not exist

> data['user_id']
=> #<Daru::Vector(42815)>
                       user_id
        0 z0udgxc0lusu1gr4xj65
        1                28080
        2                28080
      ...                  ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
data = Daru::DataFrame.from_csv('my_fancy_data.csv', headers: true, header_converters: :symbol)
```

From the documentation:

> You can specify all the options to the `.from_csv` function that you do to the Ruby `CSV.read()` function, since this is what is used internally.